# Use placeholder attribute and password type in Xpages

Tags: xpages

I have an Edit Box that I want to use a placeholder AND password='true'.  Changing password='true' causes the placeholder to not work, the password type does work.

I set the placeholder like this:  `<xp:attr name="placeholder" value="Enter Password">/xp:attr>`

You cannot set type=password or you get an XSP error telling you to use password=true instead.

BTW: I am using the placeholder instead of labels in the same style as Slobodan Lohja's popular blog post:  http://xpagesbeast.com/uxdesign/customizing-the-html-log-in-form-with-bootstrap/   (In his case, he uses passthru html so he doesn't have to deal with this issue.)

Comment: Setting password=true seems to cause it to ignore any attributes you try to set.  I was trying to add a class for using jQuery to access it.  Could this be a bug???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, but I've found it to be a useful pattern for overcoming the refusal of the default renderers to allow us to specify HTML5 types for input components.

Set a `styleClass` that makes it obvious it's a specific type of input (i.e. `passwordInput`).

Add a `scriptBlock` to the page:

```
<xp:scriptBlock>
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[XSP.addOnLoad(function(){
    dojo.query(".passwordInput").forEach(function(eachInput){
        dojo.attr(eachInput, "type", "password");
    });
});]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

This will cause *all* inputs with a class of `passwordInput` to become password fields. You can use this same pattern for any attribute manipulation, but I most frequently use it to assign [HTML5 input types](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp) to standard `inputText` components.

**Caveat:** If you have partial refresh events on your page that cause these inputs to be reloaded, make sure to include the `scriptBlock` *inside* the same refresh target. Otherwise, your plain text field will become a password field on initial page load, but will revert to being a plain text field after any events that target the field or a container thereof; if the `scriptBlock` is inside the refresh target, however, when the input is rendered, the script will execute again, once again making it a password field.

Comment: This works perfect.  Yeah, I would say this is a hack alright.  I hope IBM fixes this in the next release.  Once again, thank you very much!!