# HTML fields of type number in XPages do not accept decimals

Tags: html, field, xpages, numeric

I have the following code in my xpage connected to data source "d", the field Fld2 in the notes form is of type number.

```
 <xp:inputText value="#{d.Fld2}" id="fld21" type="number">
                    <xp:this.converter>
                        <xp:convertNumber type="number"></xp:convertNumber>
                    </xp:this.converter>
 </xp:inputText>
```

The reason for using both converter type number and input field type number is because I want to bring up a numeric keyboard on ipad. so this attribut will make the ui field of type number. in some browsers there are also some other nice HTML5 features added to the ui field, such as step arrows.

note: Specifying the number converter for the field does not make the html element of type number

My problem is that this code do not work for decimal numbers, if I enter 1,3 or 1.3 it do not recognize this as a number and strips of everything to the right of 1

if I remove the atrribute type="number" from the code everything works

I have tried to add the html5 "step=any" attribut but could not get it to work
http://blog.isotoma.com/2012/03/html5-input-typenumber-and-decimalsfloats-in-chrome/

if I add the attrribute step="0.1" I can step one decimal at a time using the ui field arrows, but when I save the document the decimals are removed

How can I add a numeric html field of type number that acceptes decimals to my xpage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out to be localized problem which was encountered when I was using Swedish language in my webbrowser. as soon as I switched to english it worked.

I had a long chat with Chintan about the problem and we discusses several solutions including adding a custom pattern, like so

```
 <xp:inputText id="inputText2" value="#{document1.myField}" styleClass="floatNumberInput" type="number">
    <xp:this.attrs>
        <xp:attr name="type" value="number"></xp:attr>
        <xp:attr name="step" value="any"></xp:attr>
    </xp:this.attrs>
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertNumber pattern="#.##0,00"></xp:convertNumber>
    </xp:this.converter>
</xp:inputText>
```

However, this did not help so I instead I came up with a workaround

First I removed the attributes, reverting back to a normal numeric xpages field

```
<xp:inputText id="inputText2" value="#{d.Fld2}" styleClass="num">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertNumber type="number"></xp:convertNumber>
    </xp:this.converter>
</xp:inputText>
```

Then I added a jQuery script that will take care of the numeric keyboard on ipad by changing the type to numeric when I enter the field and revert back to text when leaving the field.

and lastely I prevent users to enter any non numeric characters in to the numeric fields

```
$(function(){

$(".num").on('touchstart', function() {
      $(this).prop('type', 'number');
});

$(".num").on('keydown blur', function() {
      $(this).prop('type', 'text');
});

$(".num").keyup(function () {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.,-]/g,'');
});

})
```

Note: the code above uses a jQuery prop method instead of the attr method for changing an attribute because the attr method do not allow changing the type due to some issues with IE

Answer (score 1):

I guess this should help. The only different thing I have done here is tweaking the "xpage type field". I had the same problem before when I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146938/use-placeholder-attribute-and-password-type-in-xpages) excellent answer by @tim-tripcony. However, this should help you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="numberTest"></xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{document1.myField}"
        defaultValue="5.3" styleClass="floatNumberInput">
        <xp:this.attrs>
            <xp:attr name="type" value="number"></xp:attr>
            <xp:attr name="step" value="0.01"></xp:attr>
        </xp:this.attrs>
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertNumber pattern="#.##0,00">
</xp:convertNumber>
    </xp:this.converter>
    </xp:inputText>
    <xp:button value="Submit" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete" immediate="false" save="true">
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <!-- Script to overwrite the default input type text -->
    <xp:scriptBlock>
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[XSP.addOnLoad(function(){
    dojo.query(".floatNumberInput").forEach(function(eachInput){
        dojo.attr(eachInput, "type", "number");
    });
});]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
<!-- End of script block -->
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Chintan, thanks for your answer.
however, this does not seem to be an answer to my problem with saving decimal numbers. Your code only seem to add the "type=number" attribute to the html field, I did that already in my code. (btw the type attribute do not need a script to be set these days)

let me know if I overlooked something about your solution

Comment: I didn't get you. You wanted to have a number picker on an XPage and the field value should be stored as float, right? The above code does exactly what you want..please let me know if I am wrong..

Comment: I have also added the converter (which I thought you will get it, since you mentioned it in the question), this would also store the field as a number in notes document.

Comment: I already have a number picker on my xpage using type=number in my code above. the problem is that xpages do not allow me to save the floating numbers.

Comment: Create a new XPage and copy paste my code in it completely, I am sure it works.

Comment: thanks for quick reply, I cannot get it to work, here is a link to live code. 
http://www.intrapages.com/thomas/num.nsf/T.xsp

if you hit save using the default value the decimals are stripped
skype chat: thomasplace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65500/discussion-between-thomas-adrian-and-chintan-parekh).